# Spring boot, how to organize multiple profile specific datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I'm lacking solid patterns and reference, how to organize profile specific security and persistence configurations in Spring Boot, where multiple profile specific *DataSources* may co-exists for different contexts.

Let's say I have three maven profiles: *dev*, *qa*, *prod*, each of which defines different properties for database connections, JPA configuration, logging etc.

With *dev* build, Spring should authenticate users against in-memory map, which is populated on startup. This is easy to implement using *AuthenticationManagerBuilder* interface.

However, with *qa* and *prod* builds, user should be authenticated against database. Now Spring should configure a *DataSource* with profile-specific connection parameters, and use this specific *DataSource* in *UserDetailsService*, retrieving the credentials for authentication mechanism. I know how to create necessary beans, but here is the problem:

**One important fact is, the user *DataSource* is distinct from the actual business entity DataSource.** How can I define profile specific *DataSource* in security configuration, and tie the scope of this particular *DataSource* to the security configuration, making User DAO (either *Spring Data JPA repository* or injected *EntityManager*) use this *DataSource*? Is this where concept called *Persistence unit* comes into play?

Also, is it a good idea to configure *HttpSecurity* in a base class, and extend Profile specific configurations from this class, where either *AuthenticationManagerBuilder* is utilized or *DataSource* beans are defined?

Another question is, how to enable the Spring profile based on  the maven profile? I think using the common denominator for both is a bad idea, as maven profile activation by variable is one-to-one, where as *spring.profiles.active* may list multiple profiles. Is it a good idea in a first place to mix maven profiles and Spring profiles, or is there a better way to organize things?

I know it's a broad question, but it's a broad subject which I need to grasp. Is there some good examples targeting these problems?

Comment: You shouldn't be building different artifacts for different environments in the first place. Basically this means you are putting untested code in production. If you want different configs for different environments, put them in different `application-[profile].properties` and create separate `@Configuration` files for them. You can always create an application listener which check if just 1 of the profiles you allow is selected, and fail if there are multiple.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum, I think you should try to stay away using maven profiles for different environments unless you have a strong argument about building the artifacts in different ways for different purposes (ie: running different plugins, using different set of dependencies...etc). However, don't forget that whatever you are eventually building is going to be a different artifact and should go through a separate testing process. For spring boot, I prefer using `yml` configuration with separate spring profiles for separate environments.

Comment: If you need to configure beans in a different way, you can have `@Configuration` files with `@Profile` to specify which profile triggers activation or deactivation of that configuration. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles
`@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // ...

}`

Comment: Only reason to use maven profiles would be to externalize connection and infrastructure properties anyway, so maybe you are right just to stick with spring profiles.

Comment: @burcakulug I know that, but the main question was how to deal with multiple datasources in different contexts (authentication, business entities), and how to organize different configuration classes (for example should I inherit from a base configuration which is common for all profiles)

Comment: @TuomasToivonen sorry if I wasn't to the point, perhaps if you can share some gists, it might be easier to understand the exact use case. Recently, I started to gear the configuration towards the separation of properties and bean configuration, and utilize `@Conditional*` annotations for existence of property beans in the actual bean configuration classes. I guess if your property structure is different in different contexts, you can have separate property beans that just inject the properties, and have separate `@Configuration` classes that has `@ConditionalOnBean(MyProperties.class)`

Comment: @burcakulug thanks for the tip, I must get familiar with this pattern and see if it fits in my use case.

Comment: Careful with `@ConditionalOnBean` there. This is only meant to be used in auto-configuration, not in user's configuration (see the Javadoc).

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I guess in this use case, you may not really need `@Conditional*`s, but is there a particular harm for users to specify their configuration in an auto-configuration fashion if they want to have flexibility for run-time configuration?

Comment: Yes there is, otherwise we wouldn't have that limitation in the first place.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I see. It seems like it is specific to `@ConditionalOnBean` according to the javadoc due to potential issues for the ordering, I didn't see such note in a few others like `@ConditionalOnProperty, @ConditionalOnClass...etc`, am I right?

Comment: Those are static checks that are not dependent of the state of the application context. It's an entirely different thing. The note isn't there because it would be ok to use them in user's configuration. I am in the camp of those who think that stuff should only be used in auto-config though.